Is it correct terminology to refer to the complex conjugate as being distributive over addition?
On Wikipedia:Complex_conjugate#Properties, it is stated that complex conjugation is distributive over addition. Indeed, $\overline{z+w} = \overline{z} + \overline{w}$, where $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$. However, my contention is about the use of the term distributive here. On Wikipedia:Distributive_property#Definition the distributive property is defined

Given a set $S$ and two binary operators $∗$ and $+$ on $S$,

the operation $∗$ is left-distributive over (or with respect to) $+$ if, given any elements $x$, $y$, and $z$ of $S$, $x ∗ ( y + z ) = ( x ∗ y ) + ( x ∗ z )$;
the operation $∗$ is right-distributive over $+$ if, given any elements $x$, $y$, and $z$ of $S$, $( y + z ) ∗ x = ( y ∗ x ) + ( z ∗ x )$
and the operation $∗$ is distributive over $+$ if it is left- and right-distributive.


But, complex conjugation is not a binary operation and therefore does not fit into this definition of distributive. Instead, it would seem to be more sensible to refer to complex conjugation as a map $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined as $f(z) = \overline{z}$. Then we might refer to the map as being antilinear which ensures $f(z_1 + z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2) = \overline{z_1} + \overline{z_2}$, where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.
Thoughts?

A given word may get used in multiple different contexts with slightly different definitions all of the time in math. This is just one instance of that. In this particular case, "complex conjugation is distributive over addition" is the perfect description of your first equation.

Well, okay, I think saying "complex conjugation distributes over addition" is a little more idiomatic and flows a little bit better, but it's still the distributive property.

But then why not also define the distributive property in reference to maps? For example, a map $f : X \to Y$ is distributive with respect to a binary operation $$ if $f(ab) = f(a) * f(b)$ for all $a,b \in X$.

"$f$ distributes over $*$" is exactly how I'd describe that equality. I don't know what to say about Wikipedia not talking about it in the same place as you were looking, but mathematicians would totally say this.

This question could really be simplified by asking "Can a unary map be distributive?" or "Can the distributive property be applied to non-binary operators?"

Usually, as long as it feels like something distributes over something in the sense of the English word, one would say that this thing distributes over that thing. The specific meaning about two binary operations is probably only written that way since that is enough to justify the term "distributive property" in usual axioms of most algebraic structures (rings, fields, vector spaces, etc.)
